# CSS stretching element vertically to bottom if bottom is below viewport

Tags: html, css

I have a mobile responsive menu that hides to the left and comes out when someone click the hamburger.  Works perfectly, except..

the backdrop is an `<a>` element, styled as follows:

```
.backdrop.expanded,
.main-menu[aria-expanded="true"] + .backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 998;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.50);
    cursor: default;
}
```

But when it opens, its vertical extent is to the bottom of the viewport.  I want it to extend to the bottom of the page.  How do I do this?

Note that I *want* people to scroll while the menu is open, as it might be helpful.

Comment: 3 years of membership and you still don't know how to ask a question?

Comment: Actually this question was answered very quickly, and I researched it first.  There are times when providing *less* information makes the question more easy to understand.  I knew the critical part (as witnessed by the answer, the CSS was the thing to change) just not the specific change.  I seldom say things like this, but your question is leading and rhetorical.  I really appreciate the accepted answer's brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
.backdrop.expanded,
.main-menu[aria-expanded="true"] + .backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;  /* instead of: width: 100%; */
    bottom: 0; /* instead of: height: 100%; */
    z-index: 998;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.50);
    cursor: default;
}
```

As relative `width` and `height` has no effect in `position: absolute`...